# Scrolling TOC programmatically using ArcObjects in ArcMap AddIn?

Tags: arcmap, arcobjects, add-in, table-of-contents

I've created the small add-in command for ArcMap, that allows find in TOC and select the layer by it's alias or feature class name. Useful when map document contains several hundreds of layers.

The only thing that I cannot implement is - scroll TOC to selected layer. Search in docs and Internet didn't help.

Comment: I'm not actually aware of any existing button/tool/command in the ArcMap GUI that scrolls to a layer in the TOC?

Comment: I'm speaking about programmatic way. May be casting TOC from add-in as COM control or so ?

Comment: I understand that you are asking about an ArcObjects approach but what I am saying is that I know of no tool that scrolls to a particular layer in the TOC and I've been using ArcMap for nearly 20 years... Now may be I have not just pressed that magic button even in 20 years...or more likely the functionality simply does not exist even within ArcObjects?

Comment: OK, sorry, I didn't understand you. Seems, this functionality doesn't exist at all. Actually, after a long ineffectual fishing internet I suspected this sad answer. But the dream dies last...

Comment: It's good to dream! :)